# Calculate mean between consecutive rows that meet specifc condition in two columns

Tags: r

I have a df like this (a simplified version):

```
lab_id  weeks GM.CSF IFNa2 IFNg IL10 IL12p40
1  op1 2020 G4 week_1 1.6900 13.0258  5.0755 3.3068 1.3
2  op1 2020 G4 week_4 1.6900  4.4113  3.9592 2.0100 1.3
3 op10 2020 G4 week_4 2.4236  8.3186 41.7559 2.0100 1.3
4 op10 2020 G4 week_4 3.2600 18.3118 12.5456 2.0100 1.3
```

I'm trying to evaluate rows that are consecutive and meet specific criteria in two columns.

The column `lab_id` has repeat strings, however, if you look at the `weeks` column, you can have different values, in my example just appears `week_1 and 4`, but I have `2 and 3` as well.

So, the condition is:

- if column `lab_id` has the same value in two consecutive rows;
- evaluate the string in the `weeks` column, if week is different, do nothing;
- if the string in `weeks` column from two consecutive rows is the same perform the following operation;
- calculate the mean of the numerical values from the two consecutive rows;
- then replace the row for the new row with the mean calculated values;

For example, in rows 1 and 2, I have:

```
op1 2020 G4 week_1
op1 2020 G4 week_4
```

The code does need to do nothing, however, for rows 3 and 4, I have:

```
op10 2020 G4 week_4
op10 2020 G4 week_4
```

So, in this case, I need to calculate the mean of `GM.CSF IFNa2 IFNg IL10 IL12p40` between the two consecutive rows that meet the mentioned criteria.
For the rows 3 and 4, my expected result must be:

```
lab_id  weeks GM.CSF IFNa2 ...
3 op10 2020 G4 week_4 2.8418 13.3152 ...
```

As you can see, the new value is the mean from the numerical column from two consecutive rows, and now I only have one row with unique `lab_id` and `weeks` values without duplicating those two columns at the same time.

My idea for the code is to use `rowise()` function and an `if_else` statement.

```
test %>%  
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(result = eval(parse(string = condition)))
```

However, I think that this is not the correct way, because I'm evaluating two consecutive rows with specific string values in two columns, so maybe `mutate()` is a better alternative.

`mutate()` function to evaluate the condition before operating:

```
test %>%
    mutate(duplicated_w = duplicated(lab_id) & weeks == "week_4")
```

So, if condition is `TRUE`, perform `mean()` from values in the column,
however, this condition is not been evaluated correctly, because is returning me `TRUE` in rows where the condition does not meet the criteria.

These two ideas have different versions in my code, however non of them have been successful so far.

Questions:

- Is there any function to evaluate columns and consecutive rows at the same time?
- What can I do with my current alternatives?

Comment: Is it always about two rows directly following each other? This simplifies the approach dramatically imo.

Comment: Should be the case, because my df is ordered by weeks, so you always have the same ```lab_id``` with ```weeks``` 1-2-3-4 and in some case you have repeat weeks like my post, could be week 1-1 , 2-2 and so on

Comment: Do you know if there is any specific function to evaluate a condition in consecutive rows in r?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `by` to split the data based on the `interaction(lab_id, weeks)`, calculating `colMeans`, `rbind`.

```
> by(dat, with(dat, interaction(lab_id, weeks)), \(.) {
+   if (nrow(.) > 1) {
+     data.frame(.[1, 1:2], t(colMeans(.[-(1:2)])))
+   } else .
+ }) |> c(make.row.names=FALSE) |> do.call(what='rbind')
  lab_id          weeks GM.CSF   IFNa2     IFNg   IL10 IL12p40
1    op1 2020_G4_week_1 1.6900 13.0258  5.07550 3.3068     1.3
2    op1 2020_G4_week_4 1.6900  4.4113  3.95920 2.0100     1.3
3   op10 2020_G4_week_4 2.8418 13.3152 27.15075 2.0100     1.3
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(lab_id = c("op1", "op1", "op10", "op10"), weeks = c("2020_G4_week_1", 
"2020_G4_week_4", "2020_G4_week_4", "2020_G4_week_4"), GM.CSF = c(1.69, 
1.69, 2.4236, 3.26), IFNa2 = c(13.0258, 4.4113, 8.3186, 18.3118
), IFNg = c(5.0755, 3.9592, 41.7559, 12.5456), IL10 = c(3.3068, 
2.01, 2.01, 2.01), IL12p40 = c(1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your idea, I think that is the correct way, I have 10 more columns with metadata, so I suppose that in the line ```data.frame(.[1, 1:2])``` do I need to specific those columns?
Because I'm having the error: ```Error in colMeans(.[-(1:2)]) : 'x' must be numeric```

Comment: @Someone_1313 Yes, try including your grouping variables in `interaction(lab_id, weeks)`. Only include numerics in `colMeans` of course, based on your example I guessed only `1:2` aren't.

Comment: If you are using base R consider `aggregate(.~lab_id + weeks, dat, mean)` instead of `by`

Comment: @Onyambu `aggregate` is significantly slower, though, at least in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Base R functions:

```
aggregate(.~lab_id + weeks, dat, mean)

  lab_id          weeks GM.CSF   IFNa2     IFNg   IL10 IL12p40
1    op1 2020_G4_week_1 1.6900 13.0258  5.07550 3.3068     1.3
2    op1 2020_G4_week_4 1.6900  4.4113  3.95920 2.0100     1.3
3   op10 2020_G4_week_4 2.8418 13.3152 27.15075 2.0100     1.3
```

---

```
na.omit(array2DF(tapply(dat[-(1:2)], dat[1:2], colMeans)))

  lab_id          weeks GM.CSF   IFNa2     IFNg   IL10 IL12p40
1    op1 2020_G4_week_1 1.6900 13.0258  5.07550 3.3068     1.3
3    op1 2020_G4_week_4 1.6900  4.4113  3.95920 2.0100     1.3
4   op10 2020_G4_week_4 2.8418 13.3152 27.15075 2.0100     1.3
```

Comment: I like `tapply`; it is the fastest, but returns strange column classes and attributes. Remedy could be `do.call('data.frame', na.omit(array2DF(tapply(dat[-(1:2)], dat[1:2], colMeans))))` and is still the fastest. +1

Comment: @jay.sf One could use tapply with col+group on the unlisted data and it will return a matrix. Will be fastest.

Answer (score 1):

Quite similar to @jay.sf's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78129201/20002111), but different enough (I suspect)<sup>1</sup>:

```r
(by(X, interaction(X$lab_id, X$weeks, drop = TRUE), 
    \(x) cbind(x[1L, c("lab_id", "weeks")], t(colMeans(Filter(is.numeric, x))))) |> 
    array2DF())[-1L]
        lab_id  weeks GM.CSF   IFNa2     IFNg   IL10 IL12p40
1  op1 2020 G4 week_1 1.6900 13.0258  5.07550 3.3068     1.3
2  op1 2020 G4 week_4 1.6900  4.4113  3.95920 2.0100     1.3
3 op10 2020 G4 week_4 2.8418 13.3152 27.15075 2.0100     1.3
```

In case you are dealing with a massive amount of data, we might translate to `{collapse}` syntax.

Using `{collapse}`

```
library(collapse)
X |> fgroup_by(lab_id, weeks) |> fmean()
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Please let me know if not.